# MissingFormatArgument Exception in unit test

Tags: jsonpath

I am going to unit test a JSON file. One of the keys is "%changed". However, using JSONPath to test it, gives me an error. How can I successfully test it?

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.%Changed").isString())
```

```
   {
        "Open": "3,659.87",
        "Nominal": "3,722.79",
        "Change": "+73.54",
        "%Changed": "+2.02%",
        "Status": "1"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what framework or language you're using, but `%` can't be in a dot-property callout like that.  You need to use the quoted index format:

```
$["%Changed"]

or

$['%Changed']
```